# Check whether a node exists in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph where each node have three attributes: 'name', 'type', 'tag'.
I want to create a function to check whether a node exists for a given attribute and value. For example: check if a node with attribute 'tag' = '1' exists. I wrote the following code:

```
def find_node(gr, att, val):
    nodesAt5 = filter(lambda (n, d): d[att] == val, gr.nodes(data=True))
    return nodesAt5
```

And I call the function as:

```
if not find_node(G, 'tag', w):
    # do something
```

It gives this error:

```
KeyError: 'tag'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the 'd' you're referring to?  Is it present in the scope of find_node(a,b,c) ?

Comment: d is the set of attributes for node n

Comment: Ah.  So does node n have the attribute key 'tag' in it?

Comment: all nodes have the three attributes set up to some values when they are created

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  It seems pretty clear there is a node for which no `tag` attribute is defined.  I believe the bug is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Find node by attribute

Does a node exist with attribute `att` and value `val` ?

Let's create a test set:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0, name='zero', type='node', tag='group_0')
G.add_node(1, name='one', type='node', tag='group_1')
G.add_node(2, name='two', type='node', tag='group_2')
```

We want to iterate over nodes and return true if we find `val` at node's attribute `att`:

```
def find_node(gr, att, val):
    return any([node for node in G.nodes(data=True) if node[1][att] == val])
```

Test the function:

```
find_node(G, 'tag', 'group_0')
```

[out] : `True`

```
find_node(G, 'tag', 'w')
```

[out] : `False`

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary needs an entry with the key **'tag'** already in it before you can access it.  Without knowing more of the context, I can't advise further than that, though

Comment: of course all nodes have the 'type', 'name', 'tag' attributes set up when they are first created.

Comment: @AgusSanjaya Have you indented your function?  I can't tell because it wasn't written indented in your question

Comment: Hm.  Not sure then.  Hopefully someone else comes along to help.  I upvoted so maybe it'll get some more attention than it otherwise would.  :)